# Calling the appropriate function

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and having a hard time trying to call the appropriate function on my setOnClickListener, I have 3 function each have a set of editText that the user can input some double values this values are then return by the function and when the user clicks calculate displays the right information, however, I'm trying to check if there's a value either in the editText or the function so I can display the right information, but I can't figure it out.

1 function at a time works

```
public class MainWindowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button calculateButton; 
private EditText length1Text;
private EditText length2Text;
private EditText length3Text;
private EditText width1Text;
private EditText width2Text;
private EditText width3Text;
private EditText thick1Text;
private EditText thick2Text;
private EditText thick3Text;
private EditText squareYards1Text;
private EditText squareYards2Text;
private EditText squareYards3Text;
private EditText result1TotalText;
private EditText result2TotalText;
private EditText result3TotalText;
private EditText grandTotalText;

private Double length1 = 0.0;
private Double length2 = 0.0;
private Double length3 = 0.0;
private Double width1 = 0.0;
private Double width2 = 0.0;
private Double width3 = 0.0;
private Double thick1 = 0.0;
private Double thick2 = 0.0;
private Double thick3 = 0.0;
private Double syard1 = 0.0;
private Double syard2 = 0.0;
private Double syard3 = 0.0;


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_window);

    calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButtonPressed);
    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(CalculateArea1() == null){
                CalculateArea2();
                CalculateArea3();
                Total = CalculateArea2() + CalculateArea3();

            }

        grandTotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f",Total));
        }
    });

   public Double CalculateArea1(){

    length1Text = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.length1Text);
    width1Text = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.width1Text);
    thick1Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thickness1Text);
    squareYards1Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.squareYards1Text);
    result1TotalText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result1TotalText);
    grandTotalText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotalText);

    if (squareYards1Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {

        length1 = Double.valueOf(length1Text.getText().toString());
        width1 = Double.valueOf(width1Text.getText().toString());
        thick1 = Double.valueOf(thick1Text.getText().toString());
    }else{
        syard1 = Double.valueOf(squareYards1Text.getText().toString());
        thick1 = Double.valueOf(thick1Text.getText().toString());
    }

    //area 1

    double yard = length1 * width1 / 9;
    double t = yard / thick1;

    double y1 = 12.20 / thick1;
    double sy1 = syard1 / y1;

    if (thick1 == 1) {
        t = yard / 12.20;
    }else if(thick1 == 1.25){
        t = yard / 9.76;
    }else if (thick1 == 1.5){
        t = yard / 8.13;
    }else if (thick1 == 1.75){
        t = yard / 6.97;
    }else if (thick1 == 2){
        t = yard / 6.1;
    }

  Double result;
    if (length1Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        result1TotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", sy1));
        grandTotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", sy1));
        result = sy1;
    } else {
        result1TotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", t));
        squareYards1Text.setText(String.format("%.1f", yard));
        grandTotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", t));
        result = t;

    }
    return result;
}


  public Double CalculateArea2(){

    length2Text = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.length2Text);
    width2Text = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.width2Text);
    thick2Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thickness2Text);
    squareYards2Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.squareYards2Text);
    result2TotalText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result2TotalText);
    grandTotalText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotalText);

    if (squareYards2Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {

        length2 = Double.valueOf(length2Text.getText().toString());
        width2 = Double.valueOf(width2Text.getText().toString());
        thick2 = Double.valueOf(thick2Text.getText().toString());
    }else{
        syard2 = Double.valueOf(squareYards2Text.getText().toString());
        thick2 = Double.valueOf(thick2Text.getText().toString());
    }

    //area 2

    double yard2 = length2 * width2 / 9;
    double t2 = yard2 / thick2;

    double y2 = 12.20 / thick2;
    double sy2 = syard2 / y2;

    if (thick2 == 1) {
        t2 = yard2 / 12.20;
    }else if(thick2 == 1.25){
        t2 = yard2 / 9.76;
    }else if (thick2 == 1.5){
        t2 = yard2 / 8.13;
    }else if (thick2 == 1.75){
        t2 = yard2 / 6.97;
    }else if (thick2 == 2){
        t2 = yard2 / 6.1;
    }

  Double result;
    if (length2Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        result2TotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", sy2));
        grandTotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", sy2));
        result = sy2;
    } else {
        result2TotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", t2));
        squareYards2Text.setText(String.format("%.1f", yard2));
        grandTotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", t2));
        result = t2;

    }
    return result;
}


 public Double CalculateArea3(){

    length3Text = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.length3Text);
    width3Text = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.width3Text);
    thick3Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thickness3Text);
    squareYards3Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.squareYards3Text);
    result3TotalText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result3TotalText);
    grandTotalText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotalText);

    if (squareYards3Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {

        length3 = Double.valueOf(length3Text.getText().toString());
        width3 = Double.valueOf(width3Text.getText().toString());
        thick3 = Double.valueOf(thick3Text.getText().toString());
    }else{
        syard3 = Double.valueOf(squareYards3Text.getText().toString());
        thick3 = Double.valueOf(thick3Text.getText().toString());
    }

    //area 3

    double yard3 = length3 * width3 / 9;
    double t3 = yard3 / thick3;

    double y3 = 12.20 / thick3;
    double sy3 = syard3 / y3;

    if (thick3 == 1) {
        t3 = yard3 / 12.20;
    }else if(thick3 == 1.25){
        t3 = yard3 / 9.76;
    }else if (thick3 == 1.5){
        t3 = yard3 / 8.13;
    }else if (thick3 == 1.75){
        t3 = yard3 / 6.97;
    }else if (thick3 == 2){
        t3 = yard3 / 6.1;
    }

  Double result;
    if (length3Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        result3TotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", sy3));
        grandTotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", sy3));
        result = sy3;
    } else {
        result3TotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", t3));
        squareYards3Text.setText(String.format("%.1f", yard3));
        grandTotalText.setText(String.format("%.1f", t3));
        result = t3;

    }
    return result;
   }
}
```

I just did the check on the first to keep it short.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is Calculate1?

Comment: Sorry, is a function, I just updated the post thanks.

Comment: `CalculateArea2();` and ``CalculateArea3();``will never get called. As this case will never happen 'if(CalculateArea1() == null)' as this can not be null. It return double.

Comment: Actually it returns A Double not the primitive type which you could check for null.

Answer (score 0):

Give us your code so we can help, I need to see your CalculateArea{1,2,3}.

Okay mate, I think I find the solution and it is really easy. When you write OnClick() function like that you need to assign OnClick function on XML file as well so the button knows that it has a "function" to do something.

Here is an example ;

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click me!"
android:onClick="OnClick" />
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: just edit the post with the rest of the code i have. thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure is setup like that, I'll double check, but the main problem is if I call the statement above it works BUT, if I add a second condition for calculateArea3 the it find null on calculateArea1 and it crashes. I need to  check if the user is on area1, area2, area3, or all together the display results accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (squareYards1Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        length1 = Double.valueOf(length1Text.getText().toString());
        width1 = Double.valueOf(width1Text.getText().toString());
        thick1 = Double.valueOf(thick1Text.getText().toString());
    }else{
        syard1 = Double.valueOf(squareYards1Text.getText().toString());
        thick1 = Double.valueOf(thick1Text.getText().toString());
        // Toast.makeText(MainWindowActivity.this, "inside the 'ELSE' statement", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

the code above was the problem, I had to do one more check and change the values if the condition was true like this.

```
  if (squareYards1Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 && length1Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                length1 = 0.0;
                syard1 = 0.0;
                width1 = 0.0;
            }else if(squareYards1Text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
                length1 = Double.valueOf(length1Text.getText().toString());
                width1 = Double.valueOf(width1Text.getText().toString());
                thick1 = Double.valueOf(thick1Text.getText().toString());
            }else{
                syard1 = Double.valueOf(squareYards1Text.getText().toString());
                thick1 = Double.valueOf(thick1Text.getText().toString());
            }
```

Now it doesn't matter if only one area is being use or 2 or 3 or all of them, it will never find an "invalid double". I had to do this for all areas.

Thanks.